# How to use two apollo client operations in one component

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using apollo client v2.6 and am using @apollo/react-hooks to interact with my graphql queries and mutations.
The problem am getting is to make more than one apollo operation in one component. i can execute the queries and mutations but retrieving the data i where the issue is because from the code below

```
[getEvents, { data }] = useQuery(GET_EVENTS),
    [createEvent, { data }] = useMutation(CREATE_EVENT)
```

you notice that inorder to get the data from the operations i have to use the data property but the error i get is

> Parsing error: Identifier 'data' has already been declared

so is there another way i can get data from the operations without using data twice
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can rename data inline, like so:

```
const[getEvents, { data: eventsData }] = useQuery(GET_EVENTS),
const[createEvent, { data: createdData }] = useMutation(CREATE_EVENT)
```

Or just use the calls without destructuring:

```
const [getEvents, eventsData] = useQuery(GET_EVENTS),
const [createEvent, createdData] = useMutation(CREATE_EVENT)
// access:
eventsData.data
createdData.data
```

Comment: I have tried something similar to this and it works just fine